# mdichild form does not show

Tags: c#, mdichild

I have a bunch of mdichild forms already designed and would Like to show the forms as a mdichild.  I set the main form to mdi and I am able to show one of the forms as a mdichild correctly.  The code that is giving me a hassle is:

```
    public partial class KeyboardSettingsForm : Form
    {
        private mainForm _mForm;

        public KeyboardSettingsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mForm = new mainForm(); //<---mdiparent
            this.MdiParent = _mForm; //<---Commenting out this line shows the form

            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.KeyboardSettingsForm_Shown);

        }
    }
```

I am not sure why if I comment out: `this.MdiParent = _mForm;` the form will show(but not as a mdichild). Leaving that code intact, the form refuses to show. How do I get that form to show as a mdichild?

***Updated Working Code***

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    private NavigationForm _navForm;
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.mainForm_Shown);

    }

    private void mainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _navForm = new NavigationForm(this);
        _navForm.MdiParent = this;
        _navForm.Show();
    }

    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

public partial class NavigationForm : Form
{

    private KeyboardSettingsForm _wKeyboard;

    public NavigationForm(Form frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _wKeyboard = new KeyboardSettingsForm(frm);


    }

    private void NavigationForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void keyboardPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _wKeyboard.Show();

    }

}

public partial class KeyboardSettingsForm : Form
{
    private Form _mdiParent;

    public KeyboardSettingsForm(Form frm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mdiParent = frm;
        this.MdiParent = frm;

        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.KeyboardSettingsForm_Shown);

    }

    private void KeyboardSettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_mdiParent.Name);
    }

    private void KeyboardSettingsForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

you need to make `mForm` an mdi container:

```
mForm.IsMdiContainer = true;
```

Comment: I did `MessageBox.show(_mForm.IsMdiContainer.ToString());` to test if _mForm is an actual mdicontainer and the MessageBox output True.  However, I did test `_mForm.IsMdiContainer = true;` which still did not show the form.

Comment: @not even after _mForm.Show()?

Comment: `_mForm.Show()` opens another mdiparent with the KeyboardSettingsForm now showing, but only in the newly shown mdiparent mForm.

Comment: @dottedquad i need more information then, please expend the question saying why a child create a parent and not the other way around, what's MainForm, and what window is running first

Comment: I managed to get my code to work.  I edited my original post with updated code snippets that work as expected.

Comment: @dottedquad make sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to show Main Form explicitly as follows:

```
_mForm = new mainForm();
this.MdiParent = _mForm;

this.Shown += this.KeyboardSettingsForm_Shown;

_mForm.Show(); // show mdi-parent explicitly because only the application's start-up form shows automatically.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saying who is `KeyboardSettingsForm`'s parent but where you're showing the parent?

```
_mForm = new mainForm(); //<---mdiparent not shown :(
this.MdiParent = _mForm;
```

Try this

```
_mForm = new mainForm();
_mForm.Show();//show your parent first
this.MdiParent = _mForm;
```

But even above code too makes only less sense. Did you mean to do something like this?

```
public partial class KeyboardSettingsForm : Form
{
    private mainForm _mForm;

    public KeyboardSettingsForm(mainForm mForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._mForm = mForm;//Did you mean this?
        this.MdiParent = _mForm;

        this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.KeyboardSettingsForm_Shown);

    }
}
```